# In mvc using enum how to get the value?

Tags: c#, enums

I have created enum like the following,

```
     public enum colors
       {
          Red = 1,
          green = 2,
           blue = 3
       }
```

I have to use this enum into page wherever i save the colors into pages. After save i have to show which color i have saved.

But for me The result is showing like, eg: red means 1.

I have tried the following,

```
o.Colors != null ? ((Models.Enums.Colors)o.ColorMode) : 0
```

the above code i should get the red,  green, blue. but i got the result like 1,2,3...

Please Help me..

Comment: I can't understand, can you please rephrase the question? What is the expected output and current one? also what is `o.Colors` and `o.ColorMode` property type?

Comment: i am using enum to take the exact value(1) of  variable(red) like this

Comment: If I right understood your problem: use method ToString().

Comment: `int value = (int)muEnum` Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: ToString() means it coverts the int value into string only. it is not taking the exact value of the integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

```
string className = Enum.GetName(typeof(Models.Enums.Colors),
o.Colors != null ?((Models.Enums.Colors)o.ColorMode) : 0);
```

or use Generic Functions

```
private static T ToEnum(string value)
{
   return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}

private string EnumToString(T enumValue)
{
   Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
   return Enum.GetName(typeParameterType, enumValue);
}
```

For your situvation  [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) is best option

Reason: If you want to add class with space or "-" then enum is scope less

```
// Use a dictionary with an int key.
Dictionary<int, string> StyleDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
StyleDict.Add(1, "Red");
StyleDict.Add(2, "green ");
StyleDict.Add(3, "blue");
```

Then you can access This dictionary like below

```
StyleDict[1] //To get Red
StyleDict[2] //To get green
```

try for dynamic

```
StyleDict[o.ColorMode]
```

Comment: dict means what? where you declared?if exactly you know, red here, green here means this is ok. i dont know which details will come out. it is dynamically take the value. that time what will do?

Comment: sry my mistake, not dict that is StyleDict code corrected, if the red ,greenand blue are constant or dynamic you can add the dictionary, from this dictonary you can access from the key int value as i shown above

Comment: There are 3 records contains 3, 2,1  like that. it is taking the details, so check everything which one is 3- take blue. i too don't know in the list of records which one is there or not. so i am commonly taking from db `o.colormode'. whatever come it should compare the enum.

Comment: Ok try this code ;  string className = Enum.GetName(typeof(Models.Enums.Colors), o.Colors != null ? ((Models.Enums.Colors)o.ColorMode) : 0);

Answer (score 1):

have you tried below code?

```
var value = (int)model.Colors;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
    ((Models.Enums.Colors)o.ColorMode).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
public enum colors
{
 Red = 1,
 green = 2,
 blue = 3
}

colors col = selectedCol; // selectedCol is the color you select for your Applications
object val = (col != null) ? Convert.ChangeType(col, typeof(string)) : 0;
```

`val` now exactly has the result you need

Comment: here, where you gave enum? you just convert the string only

Comment: @PoliDev "selectedCol" is the value

Comment: Yes. I already get the value. i want to compare with enum and show the exact result

Answer (score -3):

It's something like this. I didn't test it.

```
o.Colors != null ? ((Models.Enums.Colors)o.ColorMode).ToString() : 0
```

Comment: That won't even compile

Comment: o.Colors != null ? ((int)  (Models.Enums.Colors)o.ColorMode).ToString() : 0